# Deserialize an XML document containing character entity references

Tags: c#, .net, xml, encoding, .net-core

I have a very old XML document that starts with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE mydoc [
    <!ENTITY reg   "&#174;">
    <!ENTITY micro "&#181;">
    <!ENTITY times "&#215;">
    <!ENTITY Agrave  "&#192;" ><!-- capital A, grave accent -->
    <!ENTITY Aacute  "&#193;" ><!-- capital A, acute accent -->
    <!ENTITY Acirc   "&#194;" ><!-- capital A, circumflex accent -->
    <!ENTITY Atilde  "&#195;" ><!-- capital A, tilde -->
    <!ENTITY Auml    "&#196;" ><!-- capital A, dieresis or umlaut mark -->
    <!ENTITY Aring   "&#197;" ><!-- capital A, ring -->
    <!ENTITY AElig   "&#198;" ><!-- capital AE diphthong (ligature) -->
    <!ENTITY Ccedil  "&#199;" ><!-- capital C, cedilla -->

...


    <!ENTITY uuml    "&#252;" ><!-- small u, dieresis or umlaut mark -->
    <!ENTITY yacute  "&#253;" ><!-- small y, acute accent -->
    <!ENTITY thorn   "&#254;" ><!-- small thorn, Icelandic -->
    <!ENTITY yuml    "&#255;" ><!-- small y, dieresis or umlaut mark -->
]>
<mydoc>
...
```

Then, throughout the document, there are lines like these:

```
<someelement>Text with &auml; or something</someelement>
```

I want to deserialize this with C#. I have generated an .xsd using `xsd.exe` and used it to autogenerate C# classes. My deserializing code is straightforward.

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(mydoc));
mydoc myDoc;

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open))
{
    myDoc = serializer.Deserialize(fileStream) as mydoc;

    if (myDoc == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Deserialization failed.");
    }
}
```

Deserialization succeeds, but when you check the deserialized `someelement` its `Value` will be:

```
" or something"
```

I checked other lines containing the special entities and they all are just cut off at the last special entity like this. How do I force the `XmlSerializer` to save that line as

```
"Text with ä or something"
```

Additional catch: this file is a few gigs in size, so I'd like to avoid making unnecessary copies and I cannot just load the entire file to memory and do stuff on it before passing it to the serializer.

Comment: Edited the title, because these entities have nothing to do with HTTP (they happen to match entities used in HTML, but that's not relevant to the problem).

Comment: This looks to me like a bug in the tool you are using. If you can't persuade the vendor to fix it, then a workaround would be to preprocess the file by doing a parse/serialize operation using some other tool. I'm not familiar enough with the tools available on .NET to offer any more specific advice.

Comment: The root rootelement has to be changed to mydoc to agree with the DOCTYPE definition.

Comment: @jdweng You're right, I made a mistake retyping it here.

Comment: I need to see sample of the actual xml to help.  The file is huge so you have to use XmlReader to parse file.  Other methods will give out of memory exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because DTD processing is disabled by default.

Try the following code:

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;

using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(Path, settings))
{
    myDoc = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader) as mydoc;
```